# post request with XMLHttpRequest javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, protractor

I tried to send post request but always get: `403` and `Authentication requires`

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "https://mywebsite.com/api/comment";
const params = 'comment=test';
http.open("POST", url, false, login, password);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params)
```

If I try to log in I get: `{"status":"nok","message":"Not JSON"}`

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "https://mywebsite.com/api/login";
const params = 'login=admin&password=admin'
http.open("POST", url, false);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);
```

I wolud like to change some data by request before I log in manually.

Comment: why you dont use fetch instead ?

Comment: I suggest asking the people who wrote this API what is expected for authentication. We would just be guessing.

Comment: I thought that it always work the same for all apps. Is Fetch bettter ?